# Are there human cells, apart from red blood cells and platelets, without a nucleus?

Tags: cell-biology

I know that blood platelets and [erythrocytes](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbiology.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F1037%2Fwhy-do-mammalian-red-blood-cells-lack-a-nucleus&ei=_pA5VfDABMa2mwWPxICwDA&usg=AFQjCNHX1uOKpqi4bxpPZqOoi_d1lmO0Tg&sig2=zq-aLiZexnTMbAe9z2yafw&bvm=bv.91427555,d.dGY) do not have a nucleus. Are there more cells in the human body without a nucleus, such as pancreas, cartilage, or lung cells?

Comment: My lecturer told me that only red blood cells and platelets lack nucleus in humans

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer**
As far as I know, red blood cells and blood platelets are the only *human* cells in our body without a nucleus.

**Background**
Erythrocytes and thrombocytes are the **only *human* cells** without a nucleus, as far as I know. However, if you count the gut as being part of the human body (in essence it is a continuation of the skin and as such it can be considered to be on our *outside*), then we are *loaded* with cells lacking a nucleus, namely all the bacteria that live in our intestines such as *E. coli*. Bacteria, being prokaryotes, lack a nucleus. In fact, there are ten times more bacteria than human cells in our gut [(Wenner, 2007)](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/strange-but-true-humans-carry-more-bacterial-cells-than-human-ones/).

**Reference**
[Wenner, *Sci Am* 2007](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/strange-but-true-humans-carry-more-bacterial-cells-than-human-ones/)

Comment: There are a [couple of them](http://biology.stackexchange.com/a/31682/3340) more if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 14):

*Wanted to give a one line answer some day!!*

[Lens fiber cells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2903674/) and [keratinocytes](http://www.nature.com/cdd/journal/v7/n12/full/4400785a.html).

Comment: That's two lines :) +1 nonetheless, interesting finds!

Comment: What do lens fiber cells and keratinocytes do? Thanks for the help, but I just wanted to know of all the common known cells, like cells of organs.

Comment: @Ace lens fiber cells differentiate to form the lens of your eye and keratinocytes form skin and hair.

Comment: @WYSIWYG Wonderful findings.

Comment: Most keratinocyte types have a nucleus. A small subtraction of keratinocytes, namely corneocytes , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corneocyte , lack a nucleus.